# Jenkins artifact resolver proxy configuration

Tags: jenkins, plugins, proxy, resolver

I've got Jenkins installed on Tomcat behind a proxy. On the other side, I've got our package repository (Artifactory)
I have create a job to retrieve a package using artifact resolver plugin but I'm getting a timeout.

Where do I need to configure the proxy settings? I already tried to modify maven settings.xml but the plugin doesn't take it into account (this works for other stuff)

EDIT: After some investigation, we have realized that Artifact Resolver Plugin can proxy http resources but not https

Thanks